# Creating a CGImageDestinationRef with CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL in C++ returns NULL

Tags: c++, macos, quartz-core, core-services

I'm trying to take a screenshot for each monitor of my macOS 10.13 setup in C++ using methods available in the some OSX frameworks but using `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` to create a `CGImageDestinationRef` destination returns `NULL` and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The problem that I think I'm having is with the line:

```cpp
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);
```

The code that I'm using is the following:

**main.cpp:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
#include <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string baseImageOutput = "/Users/bogdan/Desktop";
    std::string pathSeparator = "/";
    std::string baseImageName = "image-";
    std::string imageExtension = ".png";

    CGDisplayCount displayCount;
    CGDirectDisplayID displays[32];

    // grab the active displays
    CGGetActiveDisplayList(32, displays, &displayCount);

    // go through the list
    for (int i = 0; i < displayCount; i++) {
        std::string imagePath = baseImageOutput + pathSeparator + baseImageName + std::to_string(i) + imageExtension;
        const char *charPath = imagePath.c_str();

        CFStringRef imageOutputPath = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, charPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);
        // make a snapshot of the current display
        CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImage(displays[i]);

        CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageOutputPath, NULL);

        // The following CGImageDestinationRef variable is NULL
        CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypePNG, 1, NULL);

        if (!destination) {
            std::cout<< "The destination does not exist: " << imagePath << std::endl;
            CGImageRelease(image);
            return 1;
        }

        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, NULL);

        if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to write image to the path" << std::endl;;
            CFRelease(destination);
            CGImageRelease(image);
            return 1;
        }

        CFRelease(destination);
        CGImageRelease(image);
    }

    std::cout << "It Worked. Check your desktop" << std::endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Am I creating the destination correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.

It seems that `baseImageOutput` needs to have prepended `file://` so that the final url is valid so we have

```
std::string baseImageOutput = "file:///Users/bogdan/Desktop";
```

Instead of

```
std::string baseImageOutput = "/Users/bogdan/Desktop";
```